# Not able to Get Liferay logged in UserId

Tags: jsf, liferay

I am trying to get liferay userId (I am using primefaces 6.2 in Liferay 7).

What I have tried so far is:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

ThemeDisplay td  =(ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
long userId = td.getUserId();
```

I am getting the below error:

```
ERROR [stderr] (default task-49) java.lang.ClassCastException: com.liferay.faces.bridge.ext.filter.internal.ResourceRequestBridgeLiferayImpl cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

I have searched the problem, but not able to find out a working solution. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

I also tried using PortletRequest. Below is the code.

```
PortletRequest request = (PortletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

ThemeDisplay td  =(ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
User user = td.getUser();
```

But now ThemeDisplacy class is not found

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/theme/ThemeDisplay: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/theme/ThemeDisplay
```

I am not sure where i am missing.

Thanks

Comment: So effectively your question is not related to JSF anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch the Liferay User object, you could use the following snippet:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
User u = PortalUtil.getUser(portletRequest);
```

Please also read this [article](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/understanding-liferay-faces-bridge) about the return value of ExternalContext.getRequest() - this might be the reason of your cast error.
The article further explains that: "the ExternalContext.getRequest() method returns an `Object` instead of an `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`. When this method is used in a portal, the Object can be cast to a javax.portlet.PortletRequest."

Comment: Thanks! Can you add a small extraction from the external link? A 10 word summary or similar?

Comment: @Kukeltje I updated my answer to provide some infos to the OP

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried with the above code, now i am getting NoClassDefFound error for Portal Util.


`WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-10) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/util/PortalUtil: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/util/PortalUtil
 at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:187)
 at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)`

Comment: That is strange. It is usually part of portal-kernel and installed as a global Tomcat library. Could search for portal-kernel in your bundle?

Comment: @Andre Albert: I am using Liferay 7 bundled with Wildfly  and maven repository. Portal-kernel-5.2.3.jar is available in the Maven dependencies. But still the error is showing NoCLassDefFound for PortalUtil.

Comment: Portal-Kernel with Version 5.2.3 is unusual for a 7.0 DXP (guess something <=3). I can not fully verify it, because i am in a train traveling

Comment: i will try with lower version and will update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The fqn for PortalUtil should be `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalUtil` - so there is something wrong with your dependency and your import

Comment: @PurnimaDas make sure that your dependency is not embedded within the WEB-INF/lib directory of your portlet WAR. If building with Maven, use provided scope: `<groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId><artifactId>com.liferay.portal.kernel</artifactId><scope>provided</scope>`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andre. Its working now. You just made my day :)